# Get the class that opened my service

Tags: android, android-service

I'm doing an Accessibility Service and I want to get the Name of the `Activity` that opens my `service`, in order to respond to this specific `Activity`.

I tried using `getPackageName()`, but I only get the package of that `Activity`.

Is there any way to get the name of the `Activity`?

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need

```
YourActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Comment: If i use this, i get the name of the service Activity, not the name of the activity that opened it.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get the name of the calling Activity from Inside the Service, if this is what you're trying to achive. What you can do is pass the name of the Activity through the calling Intent:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,YourService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("Caller","YourActivity");
startService(serviceIntent);
```

and in your Service

```
onStartCommand(Intent yourIntent, int flags, int startId){
String caller = yourIntent.getStringExtra("Caller");
  if caller.equals("YourActivity"){
   //Do what you need to do...
  }
}
```

Comment: The Accessibility service starts auto when the user do a long click, so i don't use startservice(intent) to start my service. I try to adapt the code to my activity, but still not working. Thanks a lot for  your answer.

Comment: Oh, I see...I haven't noticed the Accessibility Service is a special class. I didn't try it, but there are methods for getSource() and getClassName() in the AccessibilityEvent, that you'll get in  onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event). Maybe they'll help you?